# 100% height in strict mode

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have a site which looks good in quirks mode:

- the navbar is always shown
- the content has a minimum height
- the content is streched when the page is enlarged: content height = document height - navbar height - footer height

Now, I'd like to change to the strict mode by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I tried a lot of things but I didn't get the same behaviour. The content isn't streched anymore.

I've put the code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5e1yvLxj/

In the fiddle the strict mode is activated.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="nav">
  </div>
  <div id="messages">
   <div id="chat-box">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</body>
```

main.css

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative; 
}

body {
  background-color: #004269; 
  margin-top: 112px;    /* nav */
  margin-bottom: 190px; /* footer */
}

#nav {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #227733;
}

#messages {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;  }

#chat-box {
  position: relative;
  min-height: inherit;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #227733;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: What are you calling the content? The `body`? The `messages` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one of those sticky footer techniques:

```js
document.getElementById("messages").onclick = function() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
  this.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#nav {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #227733;
  position: relative; /* force higher z-index than next divs */
}
#footer {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #227733;
}
#messages {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-top: -100px; /* match header height */
  margin-bottom: -150px; /* match footer height */
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#messages:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100px; /* match header height */
}
#messages:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 150px; /* match footer height */
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">#nav</div>
<div id="messages">#messages (click to add content)</div>
<div id="footer">#footer</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use too much position: relative and absolute. This can be useful in some cases but not here. Try the following for a change.

You can also use the calc to calculate the pixels using the percentage that the static nav and footer heights.

```css
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #004269; 
    /* nav */
   /* footer */
    height: 100%;
    
}

#nav {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #227733;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#messages
{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  height: calc(100% - 100px - 150px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#chat-box {
  min-height: inherit;
  padding-top: 0px;
    
    margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

#footer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #227733;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small JavaScript that'll do it without you're having to modify anything else you already have there:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var nav = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('nav'), null).height),
        footer = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('footer')).height);
    document.getElementById('messages').setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + (window.innerHeight - nav - footer) + 'px;');
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kobcy8o/

I verified it working in IE11 and Chrome 39.